# How To Allow Build & Distribute On Two Different Development Macs For iOS?

Tags: ios8, certificate, provisioning-profile, private-key, xcode6.1

My colleague has created a Ad Hoc Distribution Certificate and a Provisioning Profile under my login for the Apple Developer Portal.  We are trying to build and archive an iOS app for internal enterprise distribution on a set number of devices.

She has then downloaded the distribution cert and the provisioning profile on her mac and she can build and install the app on an iPad air via iTunes.

I have now also downloaded and installed the distribution cert and provisioning profile from the developer portal to my mac but I get the error message saying the following:

> No provisioning profiles with a valid signing identity (i.e. certificate and private key pair) were found. Fix Issue

What am I missing in this process?  Do I need to copy some files from her mac to my mac in order for this to work?

Is there now an easier way to do this because this process is extremely frustrating?  i.e. should I now be using TestFlight for this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to copy some files.  You need to export these certificates, with their private keys in .p12 format, using the Keychain Access Utility app, from the Mac where certificates were originally generated, to the 2nd Mac you want to use to codesign iOS apps.

Any developer certificates you download from ITC are missing their private key, and are thus fairly useless, except on the originating Mac.